# How can i check the status of my package submission?

Tags: ros, bloom-release, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I submitted the package [here](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/10929)

It's passed some jenkins builds [here](http://build.ros.org/search/?q=ros_numpy)

However, it doesn't show up as a package on [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_numpy), or in the [software list](http://www.ros.org/browse/search.php?distro=indigo&q=ros_numpy).

Is there a step that I've missed? Or does the process take longer than a few days?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230803/how-can-i-check-the-status-of-my-package-submission?/) by [eric-wieser](https://answers.ros.org/users/26065/eric-wieser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2016-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both the entry in the wiki and entry on the software list (called ROS browse) require a doc job for your package to have run:

http://build.ros.org/job/Idoc__ros_numpy__ubuntu_trusty_amd64/

As of the writing of this answer there are no builds in the link above. I believe the wiki was supposed to have an entry (a minimal one anyways) as soon as a release has been done, but that might only happen when there is no doc entry for your package (which yours does have).

Doc jobs run once every three days, so you might just be on the edge of getting a doc job run. Looking at the job configuration of the above linked doc job I see:

> Would last have run at Friday, April 1, 2016 3:00:23 AM PDT; would next run at Monday, April 4, 2016 3:00:23 AM PDT.

So I'm not sure exactly why it didn't run yet. @Dirk Thomas might have an idea why. I'll manually kick off a job for you now, but I would expect that within a week it would have run anyways. It might take a few hours since the farm is pretty small at the moment (3 machines / 12 executors).

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you can see in the history of builds the indigo doc jobs haven't been reconfigured on March 31st: http://build.ros.org/job/Idoc_reconfigure-jobs/

As the description of the doc job states it was generated at 2016-04-01 23:07:41 -0700. The first run on April 4th at 3am was the first correctly scheduled run. So all within expected behavior.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1